# Wrong distance using distanceFromLocation:

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I'm trying to find out what's wrong but it seems like the mentioned method is just returning wrong values. I'm setting coordinates in simulator, then just print them and calculate distance:

```
(lldb) p location.coordinate
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) $1 = (latitude = 51, longitude = 0.10000000000000001)
(lldb) p _oldLocation.coordinate
(CLLocationCoordinate2D) $2 = (latitude = 51, longitude = 0)
```

Now I'm calculating distance:

```
distance = (CGFloat)[location distanceFromLocation:_trackEndLocation];
```

And when I print it i get:

```
(lldb) po self.trackDistance
7019.76758
```

Now, the problem is that users tell me that app returns too big distance. As I wanted to debug it, I've checked the distance at [page to calculate distance between two points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

The results are as following:

[image]

As you can notice, the distance according to the webpage is 6.997km while Apple method tells me 7.019km. I wonder who is incorrect, Apple or the webpage and what to do with this matter. The difference isn't big, but when you accumulate it between few points it can be disturbing.

Comment: Hey did you find any clue about this?

Comment: @German I've just added solution to my problem, but I doubt you have same problem. Probably you're handling something wrong in your code, same as me ;). The framework is working ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was checking the accuracy and filtered some results out if the accuracy was bad. That's why sometimes the distance was wrong. I've fixed the accuracy filtration and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple doc page for distanceFromLocation says this:

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

I suspect Google Maps does consider the terrain between the two points, and that's why you saw a 0.3% difference in your test. However, I doubt your customers are complaining about that level of error. It's more likely the error is from a different cause.

Without knowing more about your algorithm it's hard to say, but if you're tracking distance traveled, the error might be caused by jitter in the phone's GPS coordinates. (That would cause a straight line path to look like a zigzag, which would yield a longer distance.) You could record some real data from your app to see for sure.